# KafkaProducerException on sending message to a topic

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

**Spring boot properties for kafka producer:**

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.client-id=bam
#spring.kafka.producer.acks= # Number of acknowledgments the producer requires the leader to have received before considering a request complete.
spring.kafka.producer.batch-size=0
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
#spring.kafka.producer.buffer-memory= # Total bytes of memory the producer can use to buffer records waiting to be sent to the server.
spring.kafka.producer.client-id=bam-producer
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
#spring.kafka.producer.compression-type= # Compression type for all data generated by the producer.
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
#spring.kafka.producer.retries= # When greater than zero, enables retrying of failed sends.
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
#spring.kafka.properties.*= # Additional properties used to configure the client.
```

I am getting below exception when i am trying to send message to a kafka topic :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for bam-0 due to 30004 ms has passed since last append
at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate$1.onCompletion(KafkaTemplate.java:255)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordBatch.done(RecordBatch.java:109)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordBatch.maybeExpire(RecordBatch.java:160)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator.abortExpiredBatches(RecordAccumulator.java:245)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:212)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:135)
... 1 more
```

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for bam-0 due to 30004 ms has passed since last append

I am not able to figure our why i am getting this exception. Can some one please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved by setting **advertised.listeners** in **server.properties** to PLAINTEXT://<**ExternalIP**>:9092.

Note: Kafka is deployed over aws.

Answer (score 0):

The producer is timing out trying to send messages. I notice you are using localhost in your bootstrap. Make sure a broker is available locally and listening on port 9092.

Comment: I am not using broker locally . I changed it to localhost here for security reasons . FYI i am able to telnet the broker via my machine

Comment: How about the console producer? Does that work? The error says it's expiring a batch of size one so that looks like a problem communicating to the broker somehow to me

Comment: Can i access the console producer from a machine other than broker ?

Comment: Easiest thing is to just download the Kafka package because it includes it.